# Opening ASP.NET localhost webpage in Firefox and Safari and Opera presents a logon dialog

Tags: asp.net, firefox, safari, opera

I'm developing an ASP.NET website in Visual Studio 2012.  When running the program in debug mode, VS launches the page at following URL:

**localhost:59422/myPage.aspx**

and opens it in IE. I can paste that same URL into Chrome and the page opens and functions properly. However,  when I paste it into Safari 5.1.7 or Firefox or Opera, *a logon dialog is displayed*.

Are there settings in these browsers that need to be changed in order for me to test with them as I can with Chrome and IE?  Why are they asking for a logon?

Comment: Do you get the same behavior when you clear the cache in each of these browsers?

Comment: You might have saved ***login cookie*** previously. You might want to verify with ***Chrome Incognito*** mode.

Comment: @alex: Cleared the Opera cache: same behavior.

Comment: @Win: Chrome incognito mode works fine: the page displays with no problems, and Chrome does not open a logon dialog.

Comment: @Tim What is **authentication mode** in **web.config**?

Comment: @Win:   <authentication mode="Windows"/>

Comment: @Tim Are you using **Windows Authentication**? Does your site even require Authentication? If not, could you try with **mode="Forms"**?

Comment: @Win: There's no authentication. That's the mystery. It's a password-recovery form that asks for username and email address.

Answer (score 0):

Base on your comment you do not need authentication, so you can take out `<authentication mode="Windows"/>` from **web.config**.

It is causing the problem; normally, **web.config** inside folder has some **authorizations**.

Without seeing the entire project, I could not pinpoint any details.